# Add button in TotalCommander that executes command with left folder and right folder paths as parameters

Tags: total-commander

I would like to add button to my commander(in button bar) that once clicked executes command with left foler as first parameter and right as second.

Example:
I have opened two folders:
C:\repo1 C:\repo2

I want command to execute my_tool.exe "C:\repo1" "C:\repo2"

Answer (score 4):

1. Right click on the toolbar (button bar)
2. Click on "Change..." context menu
3. Fill in the fields:

   Command: => my_tool_path/my_tool.exe

   Parameters: => **"%X%P" "%X%T"** (or "%X%P%N" "%X%T%M" for pathes with filenames)
4. Click OK